# ValueError: Target data is missing. Your model was compiled with loss=<keras.losses.MeanSquaredError ... in regression task

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am pretty new to neural networks/keras so probably I am missing something obvious. The goal of this is to put a time-series in and then predict the next value.
The dataset construction is the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import numpy as np

train_dataset, test_dataset = test_train_split(data['ma'], 20)

train_dataset = np.array(train_dataset)
train_dataset = [np.reshape(train_dataset, (train_dataset.shape[0], 1))]
test_dataset = np.array(test_dataset)
test_dataset = [np.reshape(test_dataset, (test_dataset.shape[0], 1))]
```

The `test_train_split(data['ma'], 20)` function returns 2 lists of float values. So in the end `train_dataset` is a list of a np.array if shape (380,1) and ```test_dataset`` one of size (20,1).

Now I defined a bayesian neural network:

```
hidden_units = [8, 8] #length is how many layers and the number is how many units per layer
train_size = train_dataset[0].shape[0]
inputs = layers.Input(shape=(1,))
features = inputs
for units in hidden_units:
        features = tfp.layers.DenseVariational(
            units=units,
            make_prior_fn=prior,
            make_posterior_fn=posterior,
            kl_weight=1 / train_size,
            activation="sigmoid",
        )(features)
outputs = layers.Dense(units=1)(features)
bnn_model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

Now I compile:

```
mse_loss = keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
bnn_model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
        loss=mse_loss,
        metrics=[keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()],
        )
```

And finally I try to use the `model.fit()` function like this:

```
bnn_model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=test_dataset, epochs = 100)
```

But this gives me the following error: `` ValueError: Target data is missing. Your model was compiled with loss=<keras.losses.MeanSquaredError object at 0x0000020A67D56610>, and therefore expects target data to be provided in `fit()`. ``

I tried searching online but it still doesn't make sense to me. I suspect it has something to do with how I construct the datasets but I am not sure how. Let me know if I need to provide further information and thanks for the help!

Comment: As the error states, you appear to have given `model.fit()` an X (input data) but not a y (target data). How can the model learn a relationship between feature and label if you don't pass it a label?

Comment: If I want to do regression, do I put the target data the same as the input data?

Comment: The fit() method uses the input and target data as parameters to train the model over a set number of epochs. The error occurs because the target data is not passed. Please refer to [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) for more information. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The fit() method signature reads

```
fit(
    x=None,
    y=None,
    batch_size=None,
    epochs=1,
    verbose='auto',
    callbacks=None,
    validation_split=0.0,
    validation_data=None,
    shuffle=True,
    class_weight=None,
    sample_weight=None,
    initial_epoch=0,
    steps_per_epoch=None,
    validation_steps=None,
    validation_batch_size=None,
    validation_freq=1,
    max_queue_size=10,
    workers=1,
    use_multiprocessing=False
)
```

refer to [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)

all you need to do is split the input data into X(input) and y(Target).

so

```
bnn_model.fit(train_dataset[:,:-1],train_dataset[:,-1],validation_data=(test_dataset[:,:-1],test_dataset[:,-1]), epochs = 100)
```

Should work for you

****Edit****

After a comment by AlexK I realised that I had omitted some crucial information. In the example above, I have assumed that the label or target is the last column in your data. If that is not the case, the correct column has to be picked through splicing.

Comment: Your `-1` implies that target is the last column. How do you know that's the case?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that up AlexK. That was indeed presumptuous of me. I will edit the answer accordingly. While it is not "always" true, usually datasets have label as the last column and I used the same here without pointing it out. A rookie mistake